# Pass data to another Polymer component

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I am working on a dashboard, in which I have a search panel at the top (let's call it component A), where users can enter a query. The value of this input will change a lot of other components in the dashboard (not only components that are its direct descendants or siblings). I want to send the search value from component A to component B, which should then respond by performing some action with the input value.

I have tried a few things:

1. Directly calling the function in component B. Haven't been able to get that to work at all.
2. Manually setting B's local property value and using an observer to trigger a function call. I manager to set the value, but the observer does not trigger.
3. Using a global variable, which I can easily access across components, but I still can't trigger functions in specific components.

How can I best do this?
I'm relatively new to Polymer, so forgive me if my ideas aren't completely 'Polymerised' :)

Approach 1

```
<dom-module id="component-B">
  <template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'component-B',
      properties: {
        id: '',
        observer: '_idUpdate'
      },
      _idUpdate: function(){
        console.log("HELLO");
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="component-A">
  <template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'component-A',
      idSearch: function() {
        var id = this.$.search.value;
        document.querySelector('component-B').properties.id = id;
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Could you add some code? Especially for your approaches 1 and 2. This should work theory. You can also have a look at [data-binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding).

Comment: @Maria I've added a small snippet. Hope this is enough. I think the current way of setting the value for the id property isn't observable. But I don't know how I can make the setting observable so the observer in component B triggers.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to send data to multiple elements (which might not be siblings of the firing element) you can use any of these two methods

- Use [iron-signal](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-signals) to fire the signal and then in all the elements where you want the data use iron-signal tag to listen to the signal

  ```
   <iron-signals on-iron-signal-<signal-name>="<function>"></iron-signals>
  ```
- You can also use standard HTML method `dispatchEvent` to fire a signal and then add `eventListeners` in all the element where you want data.